# Error: error:unpr Unknown Provider after updating Angular Fire from 0.0.0 to 0.9.2

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

My AngularJS app was working fine before updating Angular Fire from 0.0.0 to 0.9.2. and now I'm getting this nasty Unknown Provider error

[image]

I am using **Angular 1.3.0** and **Firebase 2.1.2**.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're injecting `$firebaseSimpleLogin` which was deprecated as of 0.9.0.

Use `$firebaseAuth` instead. It has new API, so I'd recommend reading the docs.

Comment: Deprecated <> dropped

Comment: Deprecated in 0.8.0, dropped/removed in 0.9.0. (I feel like we're a collaborative, cumulative changelog)